# Fine-uploader drag-and-drop: distinct dropzone and help div

Tags: fine-uploader

I have a webpage that contains a `<main/>` div that I am using as a dropzone. That div is covering most of the screen, and I do not want fine-uploader to modify the CSS of this specific div.

When a file is dragged onto the page, I would like to interactively display an help page. That help page is an hidden div floating above the page. I'd like to instruct the DragAndDrop module of fine-uploader to use `<main/>` as a dropzone, and to control (either by adding a CSS class, or better some of my Javascript code) the other hidden div.

For now the code looks like:

```
var dragAndDropModule = new qq.DragAndDrop({
    dropZoneElements: document.getElementsByTagName('main'),
    classes: {
        dropActive: "cssClassToAddToDropZoneOnEnter"
    },
    callbacks: {
        processingDroppedFilesComplete: function(files, dropTarget) {
            fineUploaderBasicInstance.addFiles(files);
        }
    }
});
```

where `fineUploaderBasicInstance` is an instance of `qq.s3.FineUploaderBasic`.

I tried adding a second item into `dropZoneElements` (the hidden `div`); but the approach has two issues: first the CSS code gets very messy in my case, and `display:block` is added to `<main/>` (https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/master/client/js/dnd.js#L251 ?) on Chrome, which breaks my layout – again here `<main/>` should only be the dropzone, not an element that is being modified.

Is there a way to change the behaviour of the DragAndDrop module to control a separate `div` (for example by having a callback on `dragover`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for JS control over the `help` block. CSS can easily do the job as it follows using the `tilde / squiggle` (`~`) selector (if it's not exactly next to main. In case it is, use the `adjacent` (`+`) selector) :

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="main">... your code ...</div>
<div id="help">... help notes ...</div>
```

---

**CSS Code** (if help div is next to main, as stated above, use `+`, if not, use `~`):

```
main.cssClassToAddToDropZoneOnEnter + #help {
    display: block;
    /* and other css properties when shown, maybe a transition effect or something */
}
```

Comment: That's a clever solution; didn't think about using a related CSS selector. Doesn't fix the issue with `display: block` being added to `<main/>`; but that one appears to be an issue with FU: https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1273

Comment: @MathieuLegrand your `<main/>` tag is already `block-level` since you said it's wrapping most of your page content so you could always comment `qq(dropZone).css({display:"block"})` and prevent the plugin from adding it.

Comment: I can indeed comment the line. My `<main/>` tag is `display: flex`; so Javascript moving it to `display: block` breaks my layout.

Comment: As you can see in the issue tracker, that style will be removed in the next scheduled release of Fine Uploader, 5.1.0.